# Cannot create container groups using @azure/arm-containerinstance

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-api-management, azure-container-instances, azure-sdk-js

I am trying to create container groups unsing azure javascript package `@azure/arm-containerinstance` but there is very little documentation on an I am struggling to make it work. This is the code that I have implemented :

```
const name = "SOMECONTAINERNAME";
const image = "someregisterylink.com/somename/someimage:latest-sometag";
const port = 6901;
const environmentVariables = {
  VAR1: "SOMEVAR",
  VAR2: "SOMEVAR"
};

const containerResourceRequests = {
  memoryInGB:1.5,
  cpu:1
};

const containerResourceRequirements = {
  requests:containerResourceRequests
}

const container = {
  image: image,
  resources: containerResourceRequirements,
  command: ['/bin/bash','-c','echo $PATH'],
  ports: [{port: port}],
  environmentVariables: environmentVariables
};
const cgroup_os_type = "Linux";
const cgroup_ip_address = {
  type: 'public',
  ports: [{protocol: "TCP", port: port}]
}

const image_registry_credentials=null;
const cgroup = {
  location: 'westus',
  containers: [container],
  os_type:cgroup_os_type,
  ip_address: cgroup_ip_address
  //image_registry_credentials: image_registry_credentials
}

var response = await azclient.containerGroups.beginCreateOrUpdate(
  resourceGroupName=config.resourceGroup,
  containerGroupName=name,
  cgroup);
console.log(response);
```

The response is very verbose but this doesn't show any error, and nothing is created on the azure resourcegroup.

Answer (score 0):

You can take reference of this [Github source Code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/main/sdk/containerinstance/arm-containerinstance) to create container groups using Azure ContainerInstanceManagement client library for JavaScript.

There is few Prerequisites that you requires .

**Install the @azure/arm-containerinstance package**.

Install the Azure ContainerInstanceManagement client library for JavaScript with npm:

**Currently supported environments**

- LTS versions of Node.js.
- Latest versions of Safari, Chrome, Edge and Firefox.

For Detailed information Please refer this [***dcoument***](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/arm-containerinstance)